# Warning: fOpen(GeoIP.dat): Failed to open stream - only on Wordpress Blog pages, normal pages are okay?

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen, geoip

I've got this function in my Wordpress theme directory:

```
function variable($value) {
$country_code = '';
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
switch ($value) {
    case 'prem_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_no = '888-888-8888'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AU') { $prem_no = '1900 000 000'; }
        else { $prem_no  = '0906 636 4355'; }
        return $prem_no;
        break;


    case 'prem_rate':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_rate = '$3.50'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $prem_rate = '$3.96'; } 
        else { $prem_rate  = '£1.53'; }
        return $prem_rate;
        break;

    case 'local_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $local_no = '755-555-5555'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $local_no = '1800 000 000'; } 
        else { $local_no  = '0207 111 6311'; }
        return $local_no;
        break;


    case 'sms_no':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_no = '1977 1977'; } 
        else { $sms_no  = '78887'; }
        return $sms_no;
        break;

    case 'sms_rate':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_rate = '25c'; } 
        else { $sms_rate  = '£1.50'; }
        return $sms_rate;
        break;

    case 'helpline':
        if($country_code == 'US') { $helpline = '700-777-7777'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $helpline = '1700 000 000'; }
        else { $helpline  = '0207 111 6210'; }
        return $helpline;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

This works fine for normal pages, and loads all the files listed above, and the switch works fine. However, when I go to view the blog articles I just get a blank page with the error message:

> Warning: fopen(GeoIP.dat): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc on line 314

and I can't work out why it would be different for normal pages and blog pages.

I know there are individual PHP files, but they all use the same functions file, right?

It's the GeoIP.dat it can't find, and it was doing this before last week before I added dirname(**FILE**) just before the filename.

The only difference I can think of, is my permalinks have a custom structure of /blog/%postname% - could the /blog be affecting the path somehow?

Any ideas as to why it's not working as expected just on blog pages?

UPDATE:

This is relevant function inside geoip.inc:

```
function geoip_open($filename, $flags) {
  $gi = new GeoIP;
  $gi->flags = $flags;
  if ($gi->flags & GEOIP_SHARED_MEMORY) {
    $gi->shmid = @shmop_open (GEOIP_SHM_KEY, "a", 0, 0);
  } else {
    $gi->filehandle = fopen($filename,"rb") or die( "Oops! Can not open $filename\n" );
    if ($gi->flags & GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE) {
      $s_array = fstat($gi->filehandle);
      $gi->memory_buffer = fread($gi->filehandle, $s_array['size']);
    }
  }

  $gi = _setup_segments($gi);
  return $gi;
}
```

BUMP: Can anyone throw some light on this? Wordpress seems to be stripping the path of $filename when viewing blog pages. When viewing normal pages, the full path is included.

Comment: Most likely `dirname(__FILE__)` is not what you expect it to be, because of different script file locations – `__FILE__` is always the path-filename combination to the file it is _written_ in, even if that is within an include file that gets included “from” somewhere else. Try replacing that with a fixed, absolute path – by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` plus the path to the file from there.

Comment: that would make sense.. and I can perfectly see the logic there.. but it's showing the same behaviour ie. all other pages work fine apart from the Blog ones. Even typing the entire full path including hostname in there, results in the file not found message.

Comment: _“Warning: fopen(GeoIP.dat): failed to open stream”_ – does the message look exactly like that? Because I think it should include the _path_ to the file as well inside the braces, _if_ there actually was one given. And how about the message you raise yourself in the shown code snippet, _“Oops! Can not open […]”_, does that show up as well? Otherwise, this might be coming from a different part of code maybe.

Comment: The message does look exactly like that, it doesn't give a path for the GeoIP.dat file, but gives the path of the geoip.inc file it's called from - but this has happened even changing from dirname(__FILE__) to SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and even an absolute path... So it doesn't look like it's meant to include the path
Yeah the Oops cannot open message appears straight after the trace table.

Comment: The ONLY thing I can think of.. is that all the other pages don't have /blog/ infront of them in the URL.. where as the blog does... Maybe that's affecting the path of the file - EDIT: No it's not that, because i've turned that off and it's still doing it, only for /blog..

Comment: Can you please make a debug output, using `var_dump(__FILE__, __DIR__, $filename);` at the beginning of your `geoip_open` function – and see what that says, once for the working case and once for the not-working one?

Comment: Working - `string 'C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc' (length=63)
string 'C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant' (length=53)
string 'C:/wamp/www/clairvoyant/wp-content/themes/clairvoyant/GeoIP.dat' (length=63)`
Non-working - `string 'C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc' (length=63)
string 'C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant' (length=53)
string 'GeoIP.dat' (length=9)`

Comment: I can't see anything obvious that stripping the path out at all. But I notice the different slashes in the working one... is that valid?

Comment: The content of `$filename` seems to be different – in the working version it includes the full path, whereas in the non-working one it seems to be the file name only, no path?

Comment: Yeah that's right. any idea's as to why? Could the answer be within the loop-page.php and the loop.php files? (the page one shows the normal pages, the other displays the post loop)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was creating the different output between pages.

The wordpress blog pages were being generated using a separate index.php file than the other pages - this was down to the way the template I'm using worked.

On the blog index.php template, the filename was actually being hardcoded into the index file.

Removed that, and now just the function is being used in both, all is well!

Thanks to all for your help